# Customized translation model specific to place names for translation between Japanese and other languages

Tags: google-translate

I am looking for a way to translate sentences with place names properly to a desired target language. The places will only be all places in Japan.

For example if my source language is Japanese and my target language is English, my input is `明日はフォールズシティに行きます`, in which translated into English might be `I am going to the waterfalls City tomorrow`.

*** Please be noted that the place name is just a made-up and translation result is just a sample.

The place name should be Foruzu City, and not directly the meaning of the word. So the output I expect should be, I am going to Foruzu City tomorrow.

So, my question is, how can I train a translation model that is able to handle translation of sentences consisting of place names like above?

Answer (score 0):

I've read about one method where the source/input data is run through a Named Entity Recognition program to identify person's names, city names etc and tag them.

Feeding source language sentences with NE tags/information helps a Neural Machine Translator make the appropriate translation.

There are descriptions of work on NMTs that incorporate NE tags you can find abundantly online.

Some similar work I found is described at [this Link](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W18-2407.pdf) and [this Link](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C18-1274.pdf).